# Terraform Datadog: trace_service_definition does not accept block for "query" or "formula" even tho it is in documentation

Tags: terraform, datadog

Am i doing something wrong?

```
  widget {
    widget_layout {
      x      = 0
      y      = 47
      width  = 50
      height = 25
    }
    timeseries_definition {
      request {
        formula {
            formula_expression = "query1 * 100"
            alias              = "Total Session Capacity"
        }
        query {
          metric_query {
            data_source = "metrics"
            query       = "sum:.servers.available{$region,$stage,$service-name} by {availability-zone}"
            name        = "query1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Documentation links:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/dashboard#nestedblock--widget--group_definition--widget--timeseries_definition--request--query

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/latest/docs/resources/dashboard#nested-schema-for-widgetgroup_definitionwidgettimeseries_definitionrequestformula

```
$terraform --version
Terraform v1.0.11
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/datadog/datadog v2.21.0
```

```
$terraform validate
╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on weekly_ops_dashboard.tf line 152, in resource "datadog_dashboard" "weekly_ops":
│  152:         formula {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "formula" are not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on weekly_ops_dashboard.tf line 156, in resource "datadog_dashboard" "weekly_ops":
│  156:         query {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "query" are not expected here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seam to be using an old version of the Datadog Terraform plugin:

> - provider registry.terraform.io/datadog/datadog v2.21.0

[Version 2.21.0 of their plugin](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/DataDog/datadog/2.21.0/docs/resources/dashboard) doesn't mention `formula`.

Either upgrade to the newest version or use whatever is available in 2.21.0